# \. in regular expression shows me compiler error

Tags: java, spring-mvc

when i use . regular expression in @pattern it shows me compiler error i have provided code below

```
@Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
```

for more clearance check out this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Mma0iNtwnGWm9Wa0RpN25xR3c/view?usp=drivesdk)

but it works fine in [RegExp tester](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Mma0iNtwnGdXR0bTB4SkJydm8/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: use `\\\` it's in a string

Comment: Unfortunately not. If you _really_ don't like escaping your backslashes, you could load the regular expression from a text file at runtime.

Comment: reason why reg exp works, it was programmed to pick up flaws like that and auto correct, but java regex engine assumes you fully know what u doing

Comment: @Remario no: the reason is that the site expects a regexp, not a Java String literal. It doesn't auto-correct anything.

Comment: well I think one time, a long time ago, it used to behave that way, any way we understand the error here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `\` has special meaning within the Java language, so needs to be 'escaped' within the String. We escape it by prefixing with `\`, so you need to write `\\.` instead. More information can be found the [official Java regex tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape it the backward slash: `\\`

Comment: That's a backwards slash.

Comment: my bad, I always every now and then mix them up .

Comment: Easy mistake to make

Comment: @Remario but it's also an easy mistake to fix... :) ([Edit])